# VBScript to Remove characters from Txt file except particular characters and align the result properly in single line

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write VBScript to edit a text file, keep only relevent set of numbers in each line and remove all other characters.

Here is the text file

```
Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  08 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  E0 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  07 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  81 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  85 .              


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  32 2               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  E5 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  1D .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  40 @               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  09 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  05 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  44 D               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  20                          


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  01 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  00 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  12 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  03 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  00 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  08 .               


Receive: Return Code: 0x00000000
00000000  E0 .
```

I need only Numbers starting from E0 to 1D (eight characters from E0) as highlighted in above txt file., and ignore all other until E0 appears again.

Here is the script I wrote

```
Option explicit
Dim objFSO,objFile,strText,strNewText,strNewText1,strNewText2,strNewText3
Dim strNewText4,strNewText5,Newfile,strNewText6,strNewText7
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path\file.txt", ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText,"00000000"," ")
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText,"Receive: Return Code: 0x"," ")
strNewText2= Replace(strNewText1,"Receive:"," ")
strNewText3 = replace(strNewText2,"Return Code: 0x"," ")
strNewText4 = replace(strNewText3,","," ")
strNewText5 = replace(strNewText4,"."," ")

Dim illegalChar , Result
Set illegalChar= new Regexp 
illegalChar.ignoreCase = True
illegalChar.Global = True
illegalChar.pattern = "a-zA-Z0_9"
Result = IllegalChar.Replace(strNewText5," ")

strNewText6 = Result 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path\result.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText6
objFile.Close
```

After running above script result is like

```
08                                                                 



E0                                                                 



07                                                                 



81                                                                 



85                                                                 



32 2               



E5                                                                 



3A :               



42 B               



09                                                                 



05                                                                 



2D -               



05                                                                 



01                                                                 



00                                                                 



12                                                                 



03                                                                 



00                                                                 



08                                                                 



E0
```

This is my desired output:

```
E007818532E53A42
E007818532E52C43
...
```

We need to remove all the characters after the first two digits in each line. Later we can arrange the number starting from E0 for the next 7 double digits in each line and remove all other character until E0 is found again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^0{8}\s+([A-F0-9]{2})"

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\file.txt")
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\result.txt", 2)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  For Each m In re.Execute(line)
    val = m.SubMatches(0)
    If val = "E0" Then
      If Not IsEmpty(str) Then outFile.WriteLine Left(str, 16)
      str = ""
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(str) Then str = str & val
  Next
Loop
If Not IsEmpty(str) Then outFile.WriteLine Left(str, 16)

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

The regular expression extracts 2-digit hex numbers from each line that begins with 8 zeroes, concatenates them until a value `E0` appears, then writes the concatenated string to the output file.

Comment: Ansgar you are almost there, Thank you anyway.  0506003200A9CD0506003200A9CDA0506003200A9CD07630022003
E007818532E53A4209052D05010012030008
E007818532E52C4309052D64010012030008   But i need only like this E007818532E53A42   *newline*    E007818532E52C43   continued in new line everytime.

Comment: If you need just the first 16 characters from each string you can extract those with the `Left` function. See updated answer.

Comment: Ansghar Thank you very much. We are almost complete. My result file still showing Line not starting with E0--> 0506003200A9CD05  (First line of the result)
E007818532E53A42
E007818532E52C43....          And I couldn't understand what is 'm' in the program.Forgive me if you feel i am dragging a bit :)

Comment: A much better solution :)

Comment: Append to `str` only if the variable isn't empty. `m` is the loop variable for iterating over the regular expression matches.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to apply the logic to fetch all the data contained between E0 and ID until another E0 is found and so on.

```
Option Explicit
Dim strPath, objFso, objTextFile, objReg, objMatches, match, i, arrTemp, str, temp, strResult, intTempPos, arrTempPattern
strPath = "Path\file.txt"
Set objFso = CreateObject("scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set objTextFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strPath,1,True)
Set objReg = New RegExp
objReg.Global=True
objReg.IgnoreCase=true

arrTempPattern = array("R.*","[0]{8}\s{2}","\.")
While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    temp = objTextFile.ReadLine
    For i=0 To UBound(arrTempPattern)
        objReg.Pattern = arrTempPattern(i)
        If objReg.Test(temp) Then
            Set objMatches=objReg.Execute(temp)
            For Each match In objMatches
                temp = Replace(temp,match.Value,"")
            Next
        End If
    Next    
    str = str&temp&vbCrLf
Wend
arrTemp = Split(str,"E0")
If UBound(arrTemp)=0 Then
    str = ""
Else

    For i=1 To UBound(arrTemp)
        strResult = strResult & vbCrLf & "E0"
        intTempPos = InStr(1,arrTemp(i),"1D",1)
        If intTempPos>1 Then
            strResult = strResult & Mid(arrTemp(i),1,intTempPos+1)
        Else
            strResult = strResult & arrTemp(i)
        End If

    Next
End If
Set objTextFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strPath,2)
objTextFile.Write strResult
objTextFile.Close
Set objTextFile = Nothing
Set objFso = Nothing
```

Comment: Gman, Thanks for help.                                          But the script you gave is working exactly same as mine, Both are giving same result. The result I am looking for is like this   E007818532E53A42  *newline* E007818532E52C43   so on..  we need to remove all the character after first two Digits in each line, Later we can arrange the number Starting from E0 till next 7 double digits in each line and remove all other character till E0 is found again.